# Get div with fixed position to fill up width

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following setup:

```
<div id='sidebar'></div>
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='content'>Hello World</div>

#sidebar {
  float: left;
}
#sidebar ~ * {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This allows the `#sidebar` to push the `#header` and `#content` to the right, and after that, the `#header` and `#content` take up the full width.

What I'd like to do is make the header fixed to the top of the screen, such that the sidebar continues to push it to the right, but on scroll it remains at the top of the screen.

My naive attempt is simply to set `#header { position: fixed }`. This does not work; it causes the width of the `#header` to become auto calculated based on its children.

So then I add `#header { width: 100% }`. This is closer; the width fills the screen, but it is not pushed to the right by `#sidebar`. Adding `float: left` also doesn't help.

My restrictions are:

- I don't have control over `#content` and cannot put it inside of any other tag that I control
- I don't know how wide `#sidebar` is

Can I do this with CSS without calculating the width/location of `#sidebar` in Javascript?

https://jsfiddle.net/vkL4s5Lz/1/

Comment: If the width of the sidebar is not defined...then NO. The fixed position header will be out of the document flow and so not affected by other non-positioned elements.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, that helped me to think of the answer that I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to wrap the header in a wrapper, and then fix the header's position within the wrapper.

```
<div>
  <div id='header'></div>
</div>

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkL4s5Lz/2/